# How to fix: raise ImportError("lxml not found, please install it")

Tags: python, flask, lxml, importerror, pythonanywhere

Im currently hosting my python Flask app on Pythonanywhere.
When I run my scraping script, which uses the code

```
df = pd.read_html(currentData.content)
```

I receive the error found in the title.

running pip freeze in my env displays lxml==4.9.3

I have tried adding flavor='html5lib', and recieved the same error
running pip freeze in my env displays html5lib==1.1
(This maybe means it's a bigger problem than just lxml)

I have tried running pip install --upgrade lxml

I have tried importing lxml.etree, but module lxml is not found

Comment: But are you running those commands in PythonAnywhere?

Comment: Yes, I have a bash console open through PythonAnywhere

Answer (score 0):

Sigh. I was used to vscode so I didn't realize I wasn't actually IN my venv.

used `pip install lxml` and it worked